# Long detailed listing in SELECT Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

[I've had a look and reviewed the MySQL syntax, but can't figure out the right query modifier.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

When you perform a normal select query, if there are a lot of columns (or one or two wide columns) the output wraps around the screen making it hard to read.

```
+----------------------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------
-----------------+----------------------------------------+------+-------------------+
--------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----
-------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I recall someone showing me a long time there was a way of coercing MySQL to output each column on its own line like so:

```
id: 123456
Short_Field: Boy it's short
A_Long_Field: This is quite long, wow, very lorum, much ipsum...
```

Can anyone tell me what I'd need to put in the follow query to replicate this behaviour:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN="value" LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Use the `\G` delimiter instead of `;`.  `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1\G`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski , want to make that an answer so I can give you the credit you deserve?

Comment: Ok, will do. I was searching for a duplicate but not finding one readily.

Comment: Yeah, I tried searching but, the no variation on "select query in one column, no not that kind of column" led to a positive result :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mode you are looking for is called "vertical output" and it is available when using `\G` as the delimiter in the MySQL command line client.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` = 'value' LIMIT 1\G
```

[Documentation on MySQL command line options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Note that you can apparently also set the --auto-vertical-output switch for output "wider than terminal width" (although I haven't tried it myself)